# How to specify database name when connecting to mongo docker container using docker compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I am working on a project where I use Mongo docker container to store my project data locally . I have a docker compose file in my express server which has the following lines :

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

on running **docker-compose up** I am successfully able to start the mongo container . My connectDB file goes like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI_LOCAL);
        console.log(`MongoDB connected`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("database connection error : ", error);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

MONGO_URI_LOCAL=mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017

If i go like this way then whenever i do any database related stuff all of my data gets stored in a db name "test" which i don't want , instead i want the data to get stored in a specific db name "Besocial".

I have tried the following ways so far:

1. Modified the docker-compose file in the following manner based on chatgpt suggestion but it didn't work out , the data was still stored in **test** db only.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: BeSocial
      MONGO_INITDB_CONNECTION_URL: mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/BeSocial
volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

2. I tried modifying Mongo uri to **mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/Besocial** but that too made no difference and opposite to this I was not even able to connect to my mongo container via this way.

I am  expecting someone to please tell me how can i specify the db name ?  I am open to share more info if required .
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `?authSource=admin` to the end of your connection url.